# Cordova Device plugin not showing values

Tags: cordova, device

I am running the following code but I am not getting the results I expect - I expect to see all the device information but the display stays at "Loading....". The code snippets came from [here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova_device_device.md.html#Device). I am new to Cordova and would greatly appreciate your help!!

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    function onDeviceReady(){
        //device APIs are now available
        var element = document.getElementById('deviceProperties');
        element.innerHTML = 'Device Name: '     + device.name     + '<br />' +
                            'Device Cordova: '  + device.cordova  + '<br />' +
                            'Device Platform: ' + device.platform + '<br />' +
                            'Device UUID: '     + device.uuid     + '<br />' +
                            'Device Model: '    + device.model    + '<br />' +
                            'Device Version: '  + device.version  + '<br />';
    }
</script>
<script>
    ons.bootstrap();
    window.onload = function() {
        document.getElementById("buttonText").innerHTML= 'Log In';
        }
</script>
<body>
<div style="text-align: Left">
        <br>
        <p> <strong>The following are details of this device</strong> </p>
        <p id="deviceProperties">Loading... </p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Probably you had not added Cordova properly, What kind of device are you testing?

Comment: Have you installed device plugin correctly in your project?

Comment: @Sujania Yes, when I do >cordova plugin list, I see that the "Device" plugin is installed

Comment: @Del I am testing on LG-E970

Comment: Can you give us the console log in chrome inspector?

Comment: I was able to resolve this - it was an issue with the `cordova` install on my PC. Thanks!!